# How to check the return value of the first function in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why does the following code return an empty array as a result (`[]`)?

```
$('#non-existing-id').first();
```

I thought that it should return `null` or `undefined`.

How can I check for the success then? I don't see anything about it in the documentation.

Comment: jQuery Api Documentation: https://api.jquery.com/first/

Comment: first() returns the jquery object. If it does't match, it would give you an empty object which in reality is a array of underlying properties.

Comment: @Mahedi Sabuj And what? I don't see anything about the return value in the documentation

Comment: @DinoMyte But its name is `first`. Why does it return an empty **array**?

Comment: ".first() method constructs a new jQuery object from the first element in that set." ..  from the documentation

Comment: jQuery always returns an object, a jQuery collection, regardless of how many elements are found. The number of elements matched can be found by just checking the collections `length`

Comment: @FrozenHeart: it actually returns an empty jquery object if no match is found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why does the following code return an empty array

It doesn't. It returns a jQuery object containing only the first match.

If there are no matches, that jQuery object contains zero elements.

> I thought that it should return null or undefined.

No, [the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/first/) says it returns a jQuery object.

> How can I check for the success then?

Test the number of matches using [`length`](https://api.jquery.com/length/).

```
if ($('#non-existing-id').length > 0)
```

Comment: In a real application I'm using the `find` function like this -- `obj.find('#some-id').first()`. If I understand you correctly, if the selector found something, it will return this object, not an array with this object. And if it didn't find anything, it will return an empty array. How can I check for the success in this case and use the resulting object after that?

Comment: "if the selector found something, it will return this object, not an array with this object. And if it didn't find anything, it will return an empty array"  — It **always** returns a jQuery object.

Comment: "How can I check for the success in this case " — Look at the code on the last line of the answer!

Comment: How is that ugly? What would you rather see?

Answer (score 1):

`$('#non-existing-id')` returns an empty array  since it found zero matches.

`.first()` returns zero results since it doesn't find any result in an empty array.

`$('#non-existing-id').eq(423424);` also returns an empty array `[]` as example.